# Mysql table serial generation

Tags: mysql

I have a database where a auto generate serial field is available but within the fields i have  a region wise serial issue.

Like data is

```
SL   Regional SL
1    DHK-1
2    KHL-1
3    CTG-1
4    DHK-2
5    CTG-2
6    DHK-3
7    KHL-2
8    KHL-3
9    KHL-4
```

So when i am going to add a new field my main serial no would be '10' but when i want to add the regional serial i.e. I select KHL then i want the next serial to be automatically set to KHL-5 or if i choose DHK then the auto serial would be DHK-4 which would be the last number based on the region code.

I want to maintain a single table to store the database. I know its easier to split the database based on the regions but i want to keep a single database for it.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
INSERT INTO serials (rsl)
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(MAX(rsl),4), SUBSTRING_INDEX(MAX(rsl), '-', -1) + 1)
  FROM serials
 WHERE LEFT(rsl,3) = 'KHL';
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa5bb/3)**